# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, but it works well in dev-mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

in the dev-mode it works just fine, but when I make the production file, it did make it, but when I open the server, the browser show this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Show from './components/Show'

const router = (
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
         <Route path="/" component={Show} />
    </Router>
);

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Show.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Show = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>hahaha</div>
        );
    }
});


export default Show;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var compression = require('compression')

var app = express()

app.use(compression())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
})

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="static/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    './client/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders:[
          { 
            test: /\.css$/, 
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
          },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': "'production'"
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2cAa.png)